# Adding a space to the prefix

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I would like to add for example as prefix to my bot discord his name + , + a space and command to be something like

```
bot, weather Dubai
```

With

```
bot,weather Dubai
```

It`s works but with space not.
This is my command run file

```
if(message.author.bot || message.channel.type === "dm") return;
let prefix = 'bot, ';//botconfig.prefix;
let messageArray = message.content.split(" ")
let cmd = messageArray[0].toLowerCase();
console.log(messageArray);
//let args = messageArray.slice(1);
let args = messageArray.slice(1);
if(!message.content.startsWith(prefix)) return;
let commandfile = bot.commands.get(cmd.slice(prefix.length)) || bot.commands.get(bot.aliases.get(cmd.slice(prefix.length)))
if(commandfile) commandfile.run(bot, message, args);
console.log(commandfile)
```

So how can I get the command to go with all that space? Is there a way to add it or/

Comment: Since you're adding a space, it's adding another element to the `args` array. so instead of `cmd` being `bot,command`, it's now going to be `bot,` (and the second arg will be `command`. Just take that into account a bit and your code is easy to fix.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to remove the prefix first then split the remaining string to an array. The first element will be the command, the rest is the arguments.

Try to run the snippet below:

```js
let message = {
  content: 'bot, weather Dubai'
}
let prefix = 'bot, '

// create an args variable that slices off the prefix and splits it into an array
let args = message.content.slice(prefix.length).split(/ +/);
// create a command variable by taking the first element in the array
// and removing it from args
let command = args.shift().toLowerCase();

console.log({
  args,
  command
})
```

And your code would look like this:

```js
let prefix = 'bot, ';
if (
  message.author.bot ||
  message.channel.type === 'dm' ||
  !message.content.startsWith(prefix)
)
  return;

let args = message.content.slice(prefix.length).split(/ +/);
let command = args.shift().toLowerCase();

let commandfile =
  bot.commands.get(command) || bot.commands.get(bot.aliases.get(command));
if (commandfile) commandfile.run(bot, message, args);
console.log(commandfile);
```